# How the get value returned and print out the list in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am create a program that the function gets value from a text box and calculate pi by Nilakantha method.
Here are the codes
HTML:

```
<p><input type="text" class="textbox" placeholder="Enter the number of times you want to calculate" id="maximum" onchange="getValue()"></p>
<p><button class="button" onclick="calculation(n)">Click to see the caculation procedure</button></p>
<p><ul id="resultlist"></ul></p>
```

Javascript:

```
function getValue(){
    var n = Number(document.getElementById("maximum").value);
    if (isNaN(n)){
        alert("Sorry you should input a number");}
    else {return n;}
}
var pi = 3;
function calculation(n){
    for (var k=1;k<n; k++){
        pi = pi + (Math.pow((-1),(k+1))*4)/(2*k*(2*k+1)*(2*k+2));
        document.getElementById('resultlist').innerHTML = '<li>' + pi + '</li>';
}}
```

but It is not working at all, the value from the text box should be the maximum times that the program calculates. And it should print a list to show the procedure of calculating.

Comment: what is it doing right now?

Comment: It is working but the program can only print out one result. it cannot print out all results

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the number in to `calculation(n)` at `<button class="button" onclick="calculation(n)">` as browser don't know what n is, so it probably be an `undifned` value, and your for loop won't work.

Solution: change that line to

```
<button class="button" onclick="calculation(getValue())">
```

So now before passing the value, browser will first call `getValue` to get the number input from `#maximum` and then pass it to your `calculation`.

EDIT:

If you want to show all progress, you can't directly assign value to

document.getElementById('resultlist').innerHTML which will overwrites it, you have to append the result to a temp storage and set it to html when loop ends.

```js
function getValue(){
    var n = Number(document.getElementById("maximum").value);
    if (isNaN(n)){
        alert("Sorry you should input a number");}
    else {return n;}
}
var pi = 3;
function calculation(n){
    // If you want to keep previouse result then use the commented out ones.
    // var text = "<hr><br/>";
    var text = "";
    for (var k=1;k<n; k++){
        pi = pi + (Math.pow((-1),(k+1))*4)/(2*k*(2*k+1)*(2*k+2));
        text += '<li>' + pi + '</li>';   
    }
    document.getElementById('resultlist').innerHTML = text;
    //document.getElementById('resultlist').innerHTML = text + document.getElementById('resultlist').innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<p><input type="text" class="textbox" placeholder="Enter the number of times you want to calculate" id="maximum" onchange="getValue()"></p>
<p><button class="button" onclick="calculation(getValue())">Click to see the caculation procedure</button></p>
<p><ul id="resultlist"></ul></p>
```

Comment: Sorry there is another problem. I want the program to print out all the results while it is calculating. but it only prints out one result. what can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: See my answer, you are always overwriting your resultlist in each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You got some multiple problems.

First one is you didn't define n, as @fuyushimoya already mentioned. He already solved the issue.

Second one is, you want to print a list of the calculation. At the moment you just overwrite your innerHtml in each loop.

An example for appending new loops to your list would be (see last line):

```
function calculation(){
var n = getValue();
for (var k=1;k<n; k++){
    pi = pi + (Math.pow((-1),(k+1))*4)/(2*k*(2*k+1)*(2*k+2));
    document.getElementById('resultlist').innerHTML = document.getElementById('resultlist').innerHTML + '<li>' + pi + '</li>';}}
```

But now you have to take care once you have finished one calculation. Thinkable would be a Clear-Button, which emptys your `resultlist`.

Answer (score 0):

calculation method takes an argument named n but it will throw undefined. Just need change few things

```
 <p><input type="text" class="textbox" placeholder="Enter the number of times you want to calculate" id="maximum" ></p>
 <p><button class="button" onclick="calculation()">Click to see the caculation procedure</button></p>
 <p><ul id="resultlist"></ul></p>
```

in javascript

```
function getValue(){
   var n = Number(document.getElementById("maximum").value);
   if (isNaN(n)){
    alert("Sorry you should input a number");}
   else {return n;}
}

var pi = 3;
function calculation(){
  var n = getValue();
  for (var k=1;k<n; k++){
    pi = pi + (Math.pow((-1),(k+1))*4)/(2*k*(2*k+1)*(2*k+2));
    document.getElementById('resultlist').innerHTML = '<li>' + pi + '</li>';
  }
}
```